# What does the message "circumventing systems" mean when your Google Ads account has been suspended?

Tags: google-ads

A client's (medium-sized news portal) Google Ads account was suspended a couple of weeks ago without prior warning. The only reason Google gave were the two words above. Consulting Google's help page [Advertising Policies Help: Abusing the ad network.](https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/6020954?hl=en) proved not very helpful as my client has never been involved in any black-hat SEM operations. Neither did Google respond to inquiries by e-mail or phone.

What makes Google accuse an Ads customer of "circumventing systems"? And: How can I get the account reactivated? Thank you.

**EDIT:** After talking to my client once again, I found out that they also use two accounts (not one) both for AdSense, and for Google Ads to promote their own websites (and nothing else). The accounts were suspended a couple of weeks after they had implanted a new cookie consent dialog on all their websites. May this be the cause?

Comment: Circumventing: To avoid or get around by artful maneuvering.  It seems Google thinks they are trying to cheat somehow.

Comment: When you say "news portal", that means that the site links to news on other sites, rather than have all the news on the site itself, right?   If so, it could be a problem with one of the sites that is linked to rather than a problem with the portal site itself.  (Based on the "any software that your site or app either hosts or links to" language in the link you provided.)

Comment: You tagged this as "adsense", but I believe a Google Ads account is for buying advertisements.  Is this really an AdSense issue (showing ads on the site), or is this an issue with buying ads?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: The client is a news portal sellig ad space via AdSense. And no, it's not a mere aggregator, but mostly publishes news articles written by inhouse and external editors. A fraction comes from news agencies.