# Google suddenly disaproved our ads account

Tags: google, google-ads

My client's Google ads account was suspended because of "circumventing system" although there is o attempt to do so on the landing page or site. Customer support is pretty useless as usual with Google ads even if you spend thousands a day with them. I looked through the source code and cannot find any malware or attempt to "circumvent the system" Help, please!!!!

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without more context - it could be for all sorts of unknown reasons. I provided one based on a hunch and recent phenomenon, but just know that without more details there's chance this question will be flagged as unanswerable.

Comment: Sounds like Mike offered a possible cause. See this related question:  [What does the message "circumventing systems" mean when your Google Ads account has been suspended?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130994/what-does-the-message-circumventing-systems-mean-when-your-google-ads-account)

Answer (score 1):

### Google Has Started Cracking Down on Companies Running Multiple Ads Accounts

If your client is running any type of ads under a separate Google Ads account that you're not managing, this could explain the suspension.

The reason they're doing this is because *a lot* of the time this sort of thing is done *to intentionally* try to game the system and dominate the Ads on a SERP. It's also a common tactic of spammers.

A lot of people are freaking out about it because it's fairly common that the intent is not to "circumvent the system". But instead get around organizational complexities. Let me explain.

Let's say your client has their own Ads account they have been running ads with in house for a long time, but then they decide they want to hire a partner to build a campaign for a new product or service. They keep their own ads running for their existing stuff and also have a partner running ads for the separate thing at the same time. Google is now cracking down with suspensions for this.

Sometimes companies will create a separate brand to offer products and services in their space that conflict with their main entity's brand and messaging. Google is also now cracking down with suspensions for this.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, yes, that could be the case and they are running multiple accounts, for different reasons than you mentioned, but this could be the answer,